# C programming printf

Tags: c, printf

I have to print two different strings but it crashes!
So, i think that i've just failed something at programming but i'm new and i don't know what! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char nome1,nome2;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("inserisci il nome del primo giocatore ");
    scanf("%s",&nome1);
    printf("inserisci il nome del secondo giocatore ");
    scanf("%s",&nome2);
    printf("i giocatori sono: %s,%s", nome1,nome2 );
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless your input is an empty string, the `scanf()`s exhibit undefined behavior for accessing out of bounds.

Comment: try with `%c` instead of `%s`

Comment: Read about [Buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some storage to the variables you have defined `nome1`, `nome2`

So, instead of putting it this way:

```
char nome1,nome2;
```

allocate some memory to these variables

```
char nome1[100],nome2[100];
```

Moreover, to prevent the buffer overflow, use [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets(nome1, 100, stdin);
```

So, your code be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char nome1[100],nome2[100];
    int num1,num2;
    printf("inserisci il nome del primo giocatore ");
    fgets(nome1, 100, stdin);
    printf("inserisci il nome del secondo giocatore ");
    fgets(nome2, 100, stdin);
    strtok(nome1, "\n");    //removing the newline.
    printf("i giocatori sono: %s,%s", nome1,nome2 );
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the newline.

Comment: @Barmar, added :)